# React slick and React router Link doesn't distinguish click and drag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-slick

I'm trying to make my slick slider slides link to an about page with `react-router-dom`. The problem is that it doesn't distinguish between a drag and a click. How would I make that happen, is there a way to do it with react router or would I need to add a JavaScript solution in with my own code? This is my code:

```js
import React from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "../node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "../node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
import "./App.css";

class Movies extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  render() {
    const settings = {
      dots: false,
      infinite: false,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 5,
      slidesToScroll: 3,
      arrows: false,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 1000,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
          },
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 600,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 2,
          },
        },
      ],
    };
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2> Single Item</h2>
        <Slider {...settings}>
          <div className="slickWrapper">
            <Link to="/about">
              <div className="customSlick">
                <h3>1</h3>
              </div>
            </Link>
          </div>
          <div className="slickWrapper">
            <Link to="/about">
              <div className="customSlick">
                <h3>2</h3>
              </div>
            </Link>
          </div>
          <div className="slickWrapper">
            <Link to="/about">
              <div className="customSlick">
                <h3>3</h3>
              </div>
            </Link>
          </div>
          <div className="slickWrapper">
            <Link to="/about">
              <div className="customSlick">
                <h3>4</h3>
              </div>
            </Link>
          </div>
          <div className="slickWrapper">
            <Link to="/about">
              <div className="customSlick">
                <h3>5</h3>
              </div>
            </Link>
          </div>
          <div className="slickWrapper">
            <Link to="/about">
              <div className="customSlick">
                <h3>6</h3>
              </div>
            </Link>
          </div>
          <div className="slickWrapper">
            <Link to="/about">
              <div className="customSlick">
                <h3>7</h3>
              </div>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Movies;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with simple built-in mouse events. A minimal example is given below.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardHeader from "@material-ui/core/CardHeader";
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import Link from "@material-ui/core/Link";

export default function Card() {
const history = useHistory();
const [mouseMoved, setMouseMoved] = useState(false);
// console.log(r)
const handleClick = () => {
    if (!mouseMoved) {
    history.push("/");
    }
};

return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
    <CardHeader />
    <Link
        onMouseMove={() => setMouseMoved(true)}
        onMouseDown={() => setMouseMoved(false)}
        onMouseUp={() => handleClick()}
        style={{ textDecoration: "none", cursor: "pointer" }}
    >
        <CardMedia image="" title="">
        {" "}
        </CardMedia>
    </Link>
    </Card>
);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, here is the best solution:

```
const onLinkMouseDown = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
}

<a
  href={href}
  onMouseDown={onLinkMouseDown}
  key={index}
>
 ...slideContent
</a>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72517845/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing Link and linking with JavaScript instead. It checks start cursor position and end cursor position to see if it was dragged or clicked.

```js
        let mousePosStart; 
        let mousePosEnd; 
        const mouseDownDetect = (e) => {
            mousePosStart = e.pageX;
        }
        const mouseUpDetect = (e) => {
            mousePosEnd = e.pageX;
        }
        const compareMouse = () => {
            console.log(`start: ${mousePosStart}   end: ${mousePosEnd}`);
            let diffrence = mousePosStart - mousePosEnd;
            if (diffrence === 0) {
                window.location.href = `./about`;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to fill in the link in the Slider Component like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Slickslider = () => {
const [imageState, setImageState] = useState({
display: true,
});

  const settings = {
   dots: true,
   infinite: true,
   speed: 600,
   slidesToShow: 3,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   centerMode: true,
   centerPadding: "0px",

   adaptiveHeight: false,
   variableWidth: false,
   autoplay: true,
   autoplaySpeed: 4000,
   cssEase: "ease-in-out",
   swipeToSlide: true
}

      <Slider {...settings}>
  
          <Link key={yourkey} to={`/yourLink`}> // Here comes the Link
            <div
              style={{
                display: imageState.display ? "block" : "none",
                width: `${imageState.width}px`,
                height: `${imageState.height}px`,
              }}
            >
              <img
                alt="img"
                src={yourImg}
              />
            </div>
          </Link>     
    }
  </Slider>
```

And then you have to define your Route Link in the component where you need:

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";


function YourComponent() {
  return (
<Routes> 
<Route path="/:id" element={<YourComponentTarget/>} /> 
</Routes>
)
export default YourComponent;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).